# how to reload a page using ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

admin.php

```
$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function() {
            location.href = "admin.php";
        }
    });
```

As a result I should get some new content added to the page (`admin.php`), but sometimes the page is not reloaded and I can see the new content only after pressing F5 key.

Any help?

Comment: If you're redirecting after making the AJAX request, then what's the point of making an AJAX request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I need to stay on the same page and reload it, because the new content is not visible without reloading.

Comment: Then return the content in the AJAX request and append it to the DOM without reloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your success function should be:

```
success: function() {
  location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
success: function() {
            location.reload();    // to reload the same page again
            window.location.href = "admin.php";   // to go to a new url
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call all the ajax method which are responsible to load the initial DOM on load. No need to refresh the page again.

```
function load(){
$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function() {
            //location.href = "admin.php";
            load();
        }
    });

}

load();
```

Something like above.